How to disable folder binding in VS Code Docker extension during debugging?
I’m using the Docker extension for Visual Studio Code to debug a .NET Core application running in a container. During the debugging process, the extension automatically binds my local source code folder to the “/app” folder in the container. This is problematic for me because the base image of my container already contains important files in the “/app” directory that I don’t want to overwrite.
I have looked through the extension settings and the documentation at Visual Studio Code - Docker Debugging but haven’t found a parameter to disable this automatic binding feature.
Is there a way to disable this automatic folder binding feature during debugging within the Docker extension settings? Any guidance or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.
Thank you!

Are you sure it is binding automatically and not because your Dockerfile is built by mounting the folder?

I don't think it's because of my Dockerfile. As far as I know, to bind a folder, you use compose.

Right now, I think question is missing information to recreate the issue. If you are using docker compose file, then can you please post your compose file and steps to reproduce your issue. Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example
